# JPA OneToOne and OneToMany entity instantiation/creation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My application uses a lot of OneToMany and OneToOne references between domain level value-objects, most of them are entities, either being a super class or a subclass of something.I would like to provide my application a consistent(yet easy) way to save those instances and the actual method save() is as such

```
@Transactional
public void save(Post post){

   try{
      JPA.em().persist(post);
   }catch (EntityExistsException eee){
      JPA.em().merge(post);
   }catch(ConstraintViolationException cve){
      JPA.em().refresh(post);
   }
}
```

The current problem is how to properly instantiate those object and which strategy choose in the cascadeType, i would like to save nested object when saving an object with references with other entities, it works now but only for the first time, after that i get a `Unique index or primary key violation` given that SQL `insert into Utente (passwd, DTYPE, username) values (?, 'Redattore', ?) [23505-168]`.Clearly my JPA provider (hibernate 3.6.9) fails to not update an existing row, instead it tries to insert a new entry in the DB.Here are some classes i am using:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Post extends Domanda {

@Column(nullable = false)
private String nome;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Commento> commenti;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Risorsa> risorse;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private NodoApprendimento nodo;

@Column
private int visibilità;

@Column
private boolean isDraft;
```

Post is referenced by a few classes among which i there is:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Partecipante extends Utente{


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
           fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Post> contributi;
```

Then i would like to know the proper way to initialize and persisteORupdate those referenced object in the database, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a provider problem, but a usage issue.  When you call persist, JPA does not require providers to execute an insert immediately - they are usually delayed to flush or commit time.  So you will not get an EntityExistsException in most cases.  Either way, the transaction state should be marked for rollback - you should not be relying on persist to determine if merge should be called.  Either call em.find, or just call em.merge on your entity and allow the JPA provider to determine if it should do an insert or an update for you.

Comment: Also note that since statements are not required to be issued until the flush/commit, you also won't catch a ConstraintViolationException.  You might have to explicitly call em.flush() while in a transaction to be sure the statement is issued and cause the exception to be thrown.